# How to make a function auto run in django

Tags: django

i want to set up a function auto run every day in django . it was be send a request to api/day. please help me! thankyou so much!

def get_data():
   ......

this is function i want it run only one per day.

Comment: learn celery........

Answer (score 0):

You can do such things with cron jobs. Check out the great and simple [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) package.